# how to sequentially execute activity1, 2, 3 when you are already at activity3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I am new to android programming, i built an application that has 5 buttons on it, and for each button i used a explicit intent to a image activity. for example, if button 1 is pressed then it shows image1 activity, if button2 is pressed it shows image2 activity,  similarly for all buttons.

now my problem here is, i want to modify this existing logic to press button5 (which is the last button on my application )and it should show  image1activity, image2 activity, image3 activity,  image4 activity, image5 activity in sequence with some delay
for example,
 if i have pressed button2 then it should show image1 activity+(delay)+ image2 activity
if i have pressed button3 then it should show 
image1activity +(delay) +image2 activity +(delay)+image3 activity
and so on
how to do it can anyone please suggest?

Comment: Its really not a good idea to start so may activities. You can achieve it in a single activity. Try to learn fragments, fragment transitions and Hamer framework. Handler can be used to delay any event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, creating so many activities just to display an image is not a good idea. You can create only one activity and pass the image uri according to click of a button. And on pressing button 5 you can use thread that can set image one by one after some interval of time. I have a demo that set text on click of a button one by one.. You can do something like that
[image]

Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView tv;
    Button btn;
    int i = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        tv = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.button);

        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        MyThread myThread = new MyThread();
        myThread.start();
    }

    class MyThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {

            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        switch (i)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                tv.setText("One");
                                break;

                            case 2:
                                tv.setText("Two");
                                break;

                            case 3:
                                tv.setText("Three");
                                break;

                            case 4:
                                tv.setText("Four");
                                break;

                            case 5:
                                tv.setText("Five");
                                break;

                            case 6:
                                tv.setText("Six");
                                break;

                            case 7:
                                tv.setText("seven");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass extra with the intent to the activities and based on them write condition in those activities.

Do like this :

Create the intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);

//Create the bundle
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

//Add your data to bundle
bundle.putString(“stuff”, "your flag/text here");

//Add the bundle to the intent
i.putExtras(bundle);

//Fire that second activity
startActivity(i);
```

Now in your second activity retrieve your data from the bundle:

```
//Get the bundle
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

//Extract the data…
String stuff = bundle.getString(“stuff”);
//based on the value of stuff control your activity
```

Comment: Hi Koustuv ,
Thanks for the quick reply, but i dont know how to do that can you put a code snippet or something?